# Contingency as a synonym to Emergency?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I was thinking of adding 'Contingency' as a synonym of the 'Emergency' tag since there are quite a few questions that relate to contingency, and it could be included in Emergency.

Emergency and Contingency are quite different though. Should this synonym be added? Or maybe as a separate tag?

Comment: Not all contingencies are emergencies.  One engine out early on a Saturn V, or a Shuttle abort to orbit (ATO), might require some actions to be taken, but the mission still proceeds.

Comment: @DrSheldon Then do you think Contingency should be a tag? 
I mean, I occasionally encounter questions that would use it

Comment: @Speedphoenix Maybe make a new meta question for this to draw attention to it.

Comment: @called2voyage I created the question https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1598/29286

Comment: I saw it! Hopefully it draws some attention.