# Should Contingency have its own tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I am opening this question on suggestion by called2voyage [here](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1574/29286?noredirect=1#comment5861_1574).

There currently exists an [emergency](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emergency) tag, but no [contingency](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contingency) tag. Emergencies and Contingencies are quite different.

From what I understand:

#### Emergencies

- Are not intended to be part of the main mission
- Can be solved, and the mission may be able to then proceed normally.

#### Contingencies

- Are not intended to be part of the main mission
- Are emergencies
- Will result in different mission results, and allow for partial failure of the mission (eg. allowing people to return alive, but without experiment results) rather than a complete loss (eg. everybody dies)

Examples of contingency planning in space exploration:

- All Space Shuttle missions after Columbia had rescue flights planned. See the [STS-3xx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STS-3xx) and [STS-400](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STS-400) (The last shuttle mission, STS-135 would have used Soyuz capsules rather than another shuttle for the contingency)
- Astronauts currently on the ISS can ditch the station and return in their capsules if need be.
- Probably every detail in every space mission had extensive contingency planning (especially for human spaceflight)

**Would the tag be [contingency-plan](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contingency-plan), [contingency](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contingency) or [contingencies](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contingencies)?**

One issue that would arrise with a contingency tag, is that every contingency question will likely also be tagged [emergency](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emergency).

[This new question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/45959/29286) would be adequate for [contingency-plan](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contingency-plan)/[contingency](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contingency) but not [emergency](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emergency)